# Who can help please, problem with citation and bibliography

Tags: natbib

I have problem with bibliography and citation with this document

```
\documentclass[12pt, french, fancyChapter, fancyPart, squeezeCommittee]{these}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{caption}
\geometry{inner=3.15cm, outer=3.15cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm}
\geometry{inner=3cm, outer=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{palatino} % times, palatino, 
\RequirePackage[bookmarks,%
                colorlinks=false,
                urlcolor=blue,%
                citecolor=blue,%
                linkcolor=blue,%
                hyperfigures,%
                pagebackref,%
                pdfcreator=LaTeX,
                breaklinks=true,%
                pdfpagelayout=SinglePage,%
                bookmarksopen=true,%
                bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png}
\graphicspath{{./logos/}}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Figure ,labelsep=period}
\renewcommand*{\figureautorefname}{Fig.}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}{equ.}
\usepackage[Latin,Greek]{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 
%\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[
   natbib=true
    sorting=none
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[authoryear,square]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{citesep={,},aysep={}}
%\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}

\newcommand*{\myeqref}[2][Eq.~]{%
  \hyperref[{#2}]{#1(\ref*{#2})}%
}
\def\equationautorefname#1#2\null{%
  Eq.#1(#2\null)%
}

\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
\AddThinSpaceBeforeFootnotes 
\FrenchFootnotes
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
\ayse{ foresee1997gauss}
\end{document}
```

**Update**: I tested many codes but they dont work. For example :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents} \begin{filecontents}{Dadsetani.bib}
@article{Hvala,
    author = {Hvala, B.},
    title = {Generalized derivations in rings},
    journal = {Comm. Algebra},
    volume = 26,
    pages = {1147--1166},
    year = 1998,
}

@inproceedings{Birkenmeier,
    author = {Birkenmeier, G. F. and Heatherly, H. E. and Lee, E. K.},
    title = {Completely prime ideals and radicals in Near-rings},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of Near-rings and Near-Fields},
    publisher = {Kluwer},
    year = 1995,
    pages = {63--73},
    editor = {Fong, Y. and others},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citep{Hvala}, \citep{Birkenmeier}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Dadsetani}

\end{document}
```

All I get is (?) (?)

My used editor is TeXmaker, I use windows and MiKTeX.

Comment: Why do you once `\RequirePackage{hyperref}` and once `\usepackage{hyperref}`? And the `\RequirePackage` seems a bit early.

Comment: ok. Thank you. But my problem is with biblography!

Comment: But *what* is this problem? Most of us aren't  telepaths…

Comment: oh sorry (this is my first with latex and with the forum )! yes i show you here  commands and packages used in writing my thesis. i would like to have citation like  author year in color blue ( foresee 1997). I tried  \bibliographystyle{apalike} with \usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}} 
but doesnt works

Comment: thank you for replaying me. I testes many codes but it doesn works. For example :

Comment: @demoiselleN, the new code you supplied works fine for me. Did you take a look at [Question mark instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)?

Comment: Your code loads the `apalike`, `natbib` and `biblatex` packages. This cannot possibly go well. Choose only one of these packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your given first code shows a lot of errors you must get while compiling it. Usually package `hyperref` should be called as last package, but in your case package `cleverref` has to be called after `hyperref`. Call packages only once and keep an eye on the correct order ...

One problem with the first code is that you are mixing the usages of `bibtex`, `natbib`, `apalike` and `biblatex` and `biber`.

Please do only copy code from files you got from the internet you understand. **Do not use code you do not understand!**

The following MWE shows you what you need to run `bibtex` and `natbib`. Copy it to your computer and use the name `mwe.tex` for it:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Hvala,
    author = {Hvala, B.},
    title = {Generalized derivations in rings},
    journal = {Comm. Algebra},
    volume = 26,
    pages = {1147--1166},
    year = 1998,
}
@inproceedings{Birkenmeier,
    author = {Birkenmeier, G. F. and Heatherly, H. E. and Lee, E. K.},
    title = {Completely prime ideals and radicals in Near-rings},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of Near-rings and Near-Fields},
    publisher = {Kluwer},
    year = 1995,
    pages = {63--73},
    editor = {Fong, Y. and others},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authoryear,square]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citep{Hvala}, \citep{Birkenmeier}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Open the terminal/console and use the compiling chain:

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
bibtex mwe.aux
pdflatex mwe.tex
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

Then you will get the result:

[image]

The following MWE is for the usage of `biblatex`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Hvala,
    author = {Hvala, B.},
    title = {Generalized derivations in rings},
    journal = {Comm. Algebra},
    volume = 26,
    pages = {1147--1166},
    year = 1998,
}
@inproceedings{Birkenmeier,
    author = {Birkenmeier, G. F. and Heatherly, H. E. and Lee, E. K.},
    title = {Completely prime ideals and radicals in Near-rings},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of Near-rings and Near-Fields},
    publisher = {Kluwer},
    year = 1995,
    pages = {63--73},
    editor = {Fong, Y. and others},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  natbib=true,
% sorting=none,
  style=authoryear,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\citep{Hvala}, \citep{Birkenmeier}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Follow again the compiling chain, but instead `bibtex mwe.aux` use `biber mwe.aux`. The result is:

[image]

Please study the differences of both codes.

Comment: again [?], [?]!!!!!!!!  I already work with elsarticle document class, it was good!

Comment: Thank you it works now but using bibtex mwe.aux instead of, as you recommended, biber mwe.aux ! I updated jabref (maybe this was the problem i dont know) . Now, i changed to \usepackage[ natbib=true,
% sorting=none, style=authoryear-icomp,maxbibnames=9, maxcitenames=2, uniquelist=false, backend=biber]{biblatex} for (author. et al, year) but i dont know how to change the use the color tealblue for all the citation not just the year i tested \usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ colorlinks = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes urlcolor = red, %Colour for exter

Comment: yes sorry, when installing texmaker i set options as described in https://lc.cx/xdve . I'm not very familar with latex i use it for thesis (obliged) and citation color and link are of instruction. Thank you so mutch